# Pick value from two-dimensional array based on value stored inside key?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, extract

Hi friends i am working on survey i need to extract an array from an array stored inside it

how to do it i am looking to extract answer array  based on question id for example 13 .

i have the question id with me . answer array is associated with question .

.how to extract the question array and answer array from the main array based on the value of question id for example 13

now if i need the array which has the question id along with its associated id how to do it then from my array structure?

my code is like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [que_info] => Array
                (
                    [question_id] => 13

                    [description] => Overall Customer Satisfaction.




                )

            [answers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [answer_id] => 45

                            [answer_text] => Very dissatisfied

                        )


                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [que_info] => Array
                (
                    [question_id] => 14

                    [description] => Progress (often referred to as Task Resolution or similar)


                )

            [answers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [answer_id] => 52

                            [answer_text] => None

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [answer_id] => 53

                            [answer_text] => Very little

                        )


                        )



                )

        )
```

any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, that's not a 2D array, that's an array tree. A 2D array always has an element array[x][y] for every array[x] and never any array[x][y][z].

Iterate through the array with a foreach, and return an answer list when you find an element with an id corresponding to question_id.

Example:

```
  foreach($questions as $question) {
    if($question['que_info']['question_id'] === $questionId)
      return $question['answers'];
  }
```

Comment: ya thanks for your reply you are right am a beginner in arrays :)  i will try it will i have both question and answer array it holds for the question id example 13

Comment: And I'm a bit of a besserwisser :)

Comment: i got my answer using your method was simple to do thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function find_question($array, $id) {
    foreach ($array as $arr)
    {
        if ($arr['que_info']['question_id'] == $id)
            return $arr;
    }
}

var_dump(find_question($array, 13));
var_dump(find_question($array, 14));
```